# Retrieve the first amount value from sms having two amount values, one having a decimal and another without a decimal

Tags: flutter

I want to retrieve the value INR 1806 from the below SMS, however, my flutter code returns the value INR 122222.03 instead.

```
Spent Card no. XX3172 INR 1806 13-09-23 12:02:11 HOMETEL Avl Lmt INR 122222.03 SMS BLOCK 3172 to.....
```

```
Map<String, double> _extractCreditAmtData(String body) {
    final regex = RegExp(r'(?:INR|Rs)\s*(\d+\.\d{0,2})');
    final matches = regex.allMatches(body);

    final customData = <String, double>{};

    for (var match in matches) {
      final value = double.tryParse(match.group(1)!);
      if (value != null) {
        customData['INR'] = value;
        break; // Only extract the first match
      }
    }

    return customData;
  }
```

I tried to modify my flutter code, however I am unable to succeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regular expression only matches amounts that have a fraction. If you also want it to match amounts without a fraction, use:

```
final regex = RegExp(r'(?:INR|Rs)\s*(\d+(\.\d{0,2})?)');
```

For this type of troubleshooting/development, I recommend using an online regex testing tool, such as this one: https://www.regextester.com/100066